# Nuxt3 server middleware: client ip is undefined

Tags: node.js, nuxt3, nitro

I have a middleware under `server/middleware/auth.ts` and am trying to gate some of my REST endpoints so they can only come from localhost (for the case where an internal tool communicates back to the webserver). For some reason though all the various options I tried all return undefined.

To get any of the fields below populated, is there some setting I'm missing?

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
    const ipAddress = getRequestIP(event) ||
                      event.node.req.socket.remoteAddress ||
                      'unknown'
    // ipAddress is always 'unknown' here.
}
```

Comment: That method comes from Nuxt / Nitro.

Answer (score 0):

In our project we read IP from `event.node.req.headers['x-forwarded-for']`. Since it [can hold more than one value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Forwarded-For#examples), it has to be parsed. This is our util method:

```
function getIp (req: IncomingMessage) {
  const ipHeader = req.headers['x-forwarded-for'] as string
  return ipHeader ? ipHeader.split(/, /)[0] : req.socket.remoteAddress
}
```

There is `remoteAddress` as a fallback, but it is possible, there is nothing, like it is happening to you...

Comment: x-forwarded-for would be for use with a load balancer / proxy. But I don't understand, even in that case, why the socket would not have an ip address. The client IP is necessary for the tcp connection to work, so under which circumstances would that not be available?

Comment: From https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#socketremoteaddress docs: `Value may be undefined if the socket is destroyed (for example, if the client disconnected).`  ... I am sorry, I lack understanding what runs under the hood of Nuxt's server side, so I can't provide you exact reason why it is happening :(

Comment: Maybe you should also try `req.connection?.remoteAddress` as another alternative

Comment: Or this npm package has a whole list of possible sources in readme https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-ip